# Can we call onstart() and onresume() in android indepent of any activities?

Tags: android

In my case, I want to make a specific request when Android app start without considering any activity and when we load app from background , onResume() should be called.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Application.onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()).

Answer (score 0):

u can use LifeCycleListener in Application:

```
         registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks(){
          @Override
          public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
            super.onActivityResumed(activity);


          }
         });
```